# Is there any good guide for using the Cassandra Command line Interface?

Tags: command-line, nosql, cassandra, datamodel

I wanted to try out Cassandra, and thought the easiest way to get up and running would be via the command line. I was wondering if there is a good guide to using the cli tool that is shipped with Cassandra. I am primarily looking for options to create column families, super columns, insert sample data and query them. The documentation on apache wiki is insufficient.

Comment: currently its not possible to alter the schema definition through the CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything the cli can do, which isn't much, is contained in its online help.

$ cassandra-cli 
Welcome to cassandra CLI.
Type 'help' or '?' for help. Type 'quit' or 'exit' to quit.
cassandra> ?
List of all CLI commands:
...

Comment: Why is it that I dont see any drop column, column family like commands?

Answer (score 1):

We have two interfaces cli and cql

TO use cli cassandra-cli and to use cql cqlsh -hlocalhost 9160

For documentation

http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/index

Answer (score 0):

here are some books

Cassandra: The Definitive Guide
by Eben Hewitt

Cassandra High Performance Cookbook
by Edward Capriolo

I know that the post is old but other users would probably take benefit